# In a tokamak, is there a density-dependent limit on plasma current?

Tags: electric-current, plasma-physics, density, fusion

In a tokamak, the kink limit places an upper bound on the magnitude of the plasma current.  For example, Parisi and Ball (2019) write this limit as (p. 246)
$$I\lesssim\frac{1}{q}\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0}\frac{r^2}{R}B$$
where $I$ is the magnitude of the plasma current (in A), $q$ is the safety factor, $\mu_0$ is the permeability of free space (in H/m), $r$ is the minor radius of the tokamak (in m), $R$ is the major radius of the tokamak (in m), and $B$ is the on-axis strength of the toroidal magnetic field (in T).

However, it seems as though $I$ must also be limited by the plasma density and possibly plasma temperature.  Surely, plasma current cannot remain constant as the electron number density $n$ of the plasma is decreased to zero.  Is there a known $n$-dependent upper bound on $I$ in addition to the bound above?